What Schema markup to use for a website for boat charter?
I am working on a yacht charter web sites. The site offers 7 days boat rentals (no skipper, just the boat itself). Each yacht has 7 to 12 beds and renters pay tourist tax on accommodation.
It's like car rental but with accomodation.
Here is an example of comeptiror product pages:
https://www.samboat.com/boat-rental/parham-town/catamaran/139912
https://www.yachtaris.com/en/sailing-yacht/bavaria-40-cruiser-fenix/102051/
What product schema would you use for this page?
I've considered hotel schema and product schema, but neither of them fit the purpose. I also considered vacation rentals but according to Google documentation it's not apripriate for boat that re not doocked.

For later comprehensibility, please insert the relevant part of the example into your question.
